# Account linking for google actions for smart home fails using authorization code

Tags: action, google-smart-home

I setup my `/oauth` and `/token` endpoints and start account linking in the client app. The `/oauth` endpoint is called with the following parameters:

```
{"response_type":"code","client_id":"<clientid>","redirect_uri":"https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/<myproject>", "state":"<state>"}
```

After creating the authcode and responding with a redirect to:

```
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/xxxxxx?code=<authcode>&state=<state>
```

I would expect a call to the /token endpoint, but instead I get a GET request for:

```
/r/xxxxxx?code=<authcode>&state=<state>
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried out your endpoints in the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a configuration issue with my reverse proxy which was rewriting redirects. My actions are running fine now.